# Center Webview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-layout

I am currently using the [official](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin by the Flutter team. But I am not able to center the rendered webview no matter what I do.

Here is the body of my Scaffold

```
Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'about:blank',
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controller = webViewController;
                    loadHtmlFromAssets();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

And here is the loadHtmlFromAssets function

```
loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
_controller.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(html,
        mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
    .toString());
```

}

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No unfortunately, I instead wrote the html receipt that I wished to display using the web view as a regular page itself, since our backend made allowance for it :(

Comment: Yeah, I did the same, I centred my HTML body using CSS code. I don't know if it is going to work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use:

```
Container(
  child: Center(
    child: WebView(...)
  )
)
```